# braintree.js prevents the form to be submitted to my server

Tags: javascript, spree, braintree

I’m having trouble with braintree javascript. In my spree store I am trying to add braintree drop-in UI. The issue lies when user selects braintree as a payment method and then switch to other payment method. When user selects braintree that time I call braintree.setup method so if user then selects any other payment method and click submit, Braintree js intercepts the data and tries to send it to braintree server but this data is not from the drop-in UI and I’m unable to submit the form to my server.

Comment: I'm not sure that I could answer this anyways, but much more information is needed, perhaps a code excerpt from the page

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issue with Payment method selection when I add Braintree Drop-in UI in Spree Store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30855711/issue-with-payment-method-selection-when-i-add-braintree-drop-in-ui-in-spree-sto)

Comment: I work at Braintree. I suggest you [contact our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) with more details.